# infinite load on form submit

Tags: html, node.js, forms, ejs

i have registration form i am trying to submit. but when i click, submit type button, placed in form, page goes in to infinite loading mode(circle starts spinning in tab and reload current page icon turns in to X).
HTML pages is actually .ejs but part you see here is just pure HTML

```
<div class="registration-popup" id="regpopup">
  <form action="/create-new-acc" method="POST" >
    <div class="content">   
      <h1 id="h1">Create new account</h1>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="inp"  id="name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Second Name" class="inp" id="secname"/>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="inp" id="username" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
          <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="inp" id="phone" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Address" class="inp" id="addres" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="inp" id="pass" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat password" class="inp" id="repass" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="register" value="register"  >
      <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" onclick="resett()" >
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

this is node js part there is other routing parts but i don't think they are problem

````
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const formidable = require('express-formidable');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(formidable());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'alazanidb'
});

http.listen(3000,function(){
  app.post('/create-new-acc', (req,res) =>{  
    res.redirect('/entry/signin');
  })
})```
````

Comment: where are you handling './entry/signin' this route?

Comment: @Aimsat  ` app.get('/entry/signin', (req,res) => {
    res.render('./entry/signin');
  })`

Comment: you were using ./ in your redirect, does this res.redirect('/entry/signin'); solve your problem?

Comment: @Aimsat. yes that must have been one of the problesms. but no it does not fux issue. i still have infinite reload

Comment: can you share the file structure? have you written any code to signin.ejs?

Comment: @Aimsat. https://github.com/1deme/alazani